# why are some strings not changing even after removing all whitespaces

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringi

I'm trying to make simple conditional swap between two columns,before this i wanted to know which rows will change so i created another column "col3" to monitor this.  But it appears it doesn't work all the time

for example

```
library(tidyverse)

df<-structure(list(in_sample = c(" PG", " T16-14", " T16-14", " Ta-1", 
" T5-4", " Bahrain", " Bahrain", " Bahrain", " Bahrain", " Bahrain", 
" Bahrain", " Bahrain", " Bahrain", " AS10", " Bahrain", " Bahrain", 
" Bahrain", " PG", " Bahrain", " PG", " T3-3", " T14-1", " T7-1", 
" AS10", " AS10", " Bahrain", " Bahrain", " Bahrain", " Bahrain", 
" Bahrain"), locality = c(" T4-3", " PG", " PG", " PG", " PG", 
" Tidal Channel", " Tidal Channel", " Tidal Channel", " Tidal Flat", 
" Tidal Flat", " AS10", " Tidal Channel", " Tidal Flat", " Bahrain", 
" Foreshore", " MP02", " MP4", " T4-3", " Awaiting Systematics", 
" T4-2", " PG", " PG", " PG", " Bahrain", " Bahrain", " MP02", 
" MP14", " MP14", " MP14", " Tidal Flat")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df%>% 
 mutate(across(where(is.character), str_trim))%>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), str_remove_all, pattern = fixed(" ")))%>%
  mutate(col3=if_else(in_sample== c("Bahrain", "PG"), "foo", "bar", missing = NULL))
```

some instances just refuse to change (**see "col3"**), but why ?

i've tried several ways but this seems to evade me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `%in%` instead of `==` help?

```
df%>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), str_trim))%>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), str_remove_all, pattern = fixed(" ")))%>%
  mutate(col3=if_else(in_sample %in% c("Bahrain", "PG"), "foo", "bar", missing = NULL))
```